# What exactly is Fuel blockchain?

Tags: rollups, l2, modular-blockchains

They describe themselves as execution layer for the modular blockchain, but what exactly does this mean?

If they are the execution layer, where are the other functionality/layer? Consensus layer, data availability etc?

Is it is own stand alone blockchain network?

How can it be used with other blockchains?

On their website here https://www.fuel.network/ you see wordings like:

> The World's Fastest Modular Execution Layer

> What is fuel
> The fastest execution layer for modular blockchains

So what exactly is it. Is it just a layer 2 blockchain on Ethereum? Or it is something more elaborate?